# Theming and layout in yii framework

Tags: php, layout, yii, themes

I am a newbie in Yii Framework and creating a CRM which is module based.
Using different tutorials I am able to create my own theme, but now I am stucked at one point.

In my theme, the upper `<nav>` and left `<nav>` remains the *same* throughout the app, until user is logged in. That's why I made it a part of my **main.php**, but in the login page there are no buttons to show, just simple *login form* with 2 *textfields*.

How can I implement this form in my application using custom themes?

I have tried to define a layout in that particular action but not succeeded. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate and show some code, I might be able to give you ideas but I don't clearly understand the issue.

Comment: This question is not related to code as layouts in yii framework have been created by folder structure and single array index in main.php file. I simply want to know that is there any way to use different theme for only one page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a custom layout for your view is the right way to go.
You can either set the layout in the controller action or in the view.

```
$this->layout = "//layouts/mylayout";
```

Note that the default layouts *column1.php* and *column2.php* also use the *main.php* layout file.

Comment: What is your ouput? a) Just the "raw" contents? -> Layout file not found. b) No visible changes? -> Layout does not get applied.
Which version of Yii are you using?

Comment: yeah the contents are shown in a raw format and you are right the error is in path i have used layout instead of layouts. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Try this step by step :

1. Create New theme

   You can create a new theme and add this to the directory
   **Application_Root/themes**.

   Look at the themes/classic directory to get an an idea of the structure of the directory.
   The important file (at this stage) is :-
   **Application_Root/themes/views/layouts/main.php**
2. Customise your theme contents

   Copy the css, image, js files etc to the correct directory and change the main.php file to your liking. For example, if your main.php says

   <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">

   Then you will have a file 
   **Application_Root/css/mystyle.css**
3. Create the content placeholder.

   Somewhere in your main.php, there will be a placeholder for dynamic text, which is specified by.

   <?php echo $content; ?>
4. Tell yii to use the theme.
   Change the file **Application_Root/protected/config/main.php** by adding the following line just before the last line (containing the closing bracket).

   'theme'=>'surveyhub'
5. Create the layout placeholders.

   Create an HTML segment that will be written into the $contents portion of main.php. Call it for example one_column.php. The file path will therefore be **Application_Root/themes/views/layouts/one_column.php** In that file, where you want the dynamic text to be placed, create a placeholder.

   <?php echo $content; ?>
6. Tell Yii to use the layout.

   In the file **Application_Root/protected/components/Controller.php**, add or modify the layout variable to read :

   public $layout='//layouts/one_column.php';
7. Refresh the page