# Yii: how to set layout in main.php (config file)?

Tags: layout, frameworks, yii

I found this link
[Theming and layout in yii framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313930/theming-and-layout-in-yii-framework)
but it describes how to set custom layout in controller.

Is it possible to set custom layout within config file (main.php)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes You can . Just Add the [layout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#layout-detail) property to your application config

```
'layout'=>'your_layout_name'
```

Keep in mind that the above configuration is used only if the [CController layout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#layout-detail) property is set to `null`.

Comment: whats the problem?  Did you assigned any value to the CController->layout? It should be set to null(or dont specify, its default is null). And remember that the above line is to be added to the config.php main array not inside the components array

Comment: I didn't assign any value in CController. Just in main.php

Comment: then pls add echo Yii::app()->layout in any view and post the output here

Comment: You right, post in index view printed my layout. The problem is in the controller. If I dump it there I get column1 layer then.

Comment: are you using a base controller. The skeleton app generated by gii by default extends from components/Controller. So commentout the layout attribute there and try again

Comment: Yes, component controller exists. I removed it and now $this->layout  dumps null.

Comment: isnt it rendering with the layout specified in config?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15410/discussion-between-dingd0ng-and-anthony)

Comment: change `'layout' => '//layout/index'` to `'layout' => index'` no need to specify the path